# How do I fix my models subsurf deformity?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have no idea what is wrong with my model after beveling the edges and using the subsurf modifier (not applied). For some reason the subsurf creates an odd deformity. I've located the source to a certain face shown below, however I do not know how to fix it.

The model without subsurf:
[image]

The model with subsurf:
[image]

The model with subsurf when the face the causes the problem is deleted:
[image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Subsurf doesn't work well with N-gons, I can see clearly that the to left face in the image is an N-gon, you might also need to clean your mesh using Remove Double Vertices

Comment: @moonboots Sure, here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51491

Comment: @Georges I do not know which specific N-gon you refer to, but I will try to fix them and yes I have removed double vertices.

Comment: @TheZazern The "top left" face, sorry for the typo in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

As Georges said, your topology is not good, you have ngons and triangles. You need to rethink your topology with quads, sometimes triangles if it's really necessary. Here is a try that seems to works:

[image]